# Unable to pass the 2nd item(router command) in python list to network device

Tags: python-3.x, pexpect

1. I have a text file which has the router IPs (ips.txt)
2. I have a text file which has the commands that needs to be passed to the router (magiccmd.txt)

I have opened the files ips.txt and magiccmd.txt files and converted the string to list. So now my IP addresses are saved as a list 'ip_add_list' and my commands are saved as a list 'magic_list'.

Now using a 'for' loop I can SSH into the 1st router and execute the 1st command. Similarly the script spawns into the 2nd router and executes the 1st command. Using the 'for' loop I am able to pick the items from 'ip_add_list'. But I am only able to pick the 1st item from the list 'magic_list'. It is not able to pick the 2nd item from the list 'magic_list'

Can someone let me know what's missing in my script? Why does it not execute the 2nd command from the list?

I have gone through different articles specific to picking commands from a .txt file and passing to a router. I can see articles specific to paramiko, but don't find something related to 'pexpect'.

```
#!/usr/local/bin python3.6
import pexpect
import sys
import time
import re
```

```
ssh_un = "remotessh"
```

```
def dologinRG(child):
    print ('logging into RG')
    # Enter Password
    child.expect ('password:')
    child.sendline ('test')
    return
```

```
def domagiccmd(child):
    print ('issue magic commands')
    for magic_cmds in magic_list:
        print (magic_cmds)
        child.expect ('NOS/')
        child.sendline ('magic')
        child.expect ('NOS/')
        child.sendline (magic_cmds)
        child.expect ('NOS/')
        return
```

```
for ip_string in open("ips.txt"):
    ip_add_list = ip_string.strip().split(',')
    print (ip_add_list)
    for magic_string in open('magiccmd.txt'):
        magic_list = magic_string.strip().split(',')
        print (magic_list)
        for linux_string in open('linuxcmd.txt'):
            linux_list = linux_string.strip().split(',')
```

```
for wan_ip in ip_add_list:
    print (wan_ip)
    child = pexpect.spawnu ('ssh %s@%s' % (ssh_un, wan_ip), logfile=sys.stdout, timeout = None)
    dologinRG(child)
    domagiccmd(child)
```

Comment: Remove the `return` statement from `domagiccmd()`.

Comment: Hi Emily - Thanks for your response. Once I commented out the 'return' in domagiccmd it proceeded with the next command. But it does not issue the 2nd command. I believe the 2nd command expects 'expect' prompt and since the 'expect' prompt is already used by the 1st command, it does not proceed. Does this make sense? can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

I have got this working:

```
import pexpect
import sys
import time
import re

ssh_un = "remotessh"

def dologinRGmagic(child):
    print ('logging into RG')
    prompt = child.expect(['password:', r"yes/no",pexpect.EOF])
    print (prompt)
    if prompt == 0:
        child.sendline ('Alcatel')
        child.expect ('NOS/')
        child.sendline ('magic')
        child.expect ('NOS/')
    elif prompt == 1:
        child.sendline ('yes')
        child.expect ('password:')
        child.sendline ('Alcatel')
        child.expect ('NOS/')
        child.sendline ('magic')
        child.expect ('NOS/')
    return

def dologinRGlinux(child):
    print ('logging into RG linux prompt')
    child.sendline ('!')
    child.expect ('#')
    return

def domagiccmd(child):
    print ('issue magic commands')
    for magic_cmds in magic_list:
        child.sendline (magic_cmds)
        child.expect ('NOS/')

def dolinuxcmd(child):
    print ('issue linux commands')
    for linux_cmds in linux_list:
        child.sendline (linux_cmds)
        child.expect ('#')

for ip_string in open("ips.txt"):
    ip_add_list = ip_string.strip().split(',')
    print (ip_add_list)
    for magic_string in open('magiccmd.txt'):
        magic_list = magic_string.strip().split(',')
        print (magic_list)
        for linux_string in open('linuxcmd.txt'):
            linux_list = linux_string.strip().split(',')
            print (linux_list)

for wan_ip in ip_add_list:
    print ('logging into RG', wan_ip)
    child = pexpect.spawnu ('ssh %s@%s' % (ssh_un, wan_ip),
                            logfile = open('/tmp/rglogs.txt','a'),
                            timeout = None)
    dologinRGmagic(child)
    domagiccmd(child)
    dologinRGlinux(child)
    dolinuxcmd(child)
```